# Spring framework -  singleton bean

Tags: spring, framework

Здравствуйте! По умолчанию все бины в фабрике создаваемой Spring-ом - синглтон. В связи с чем вопрос:
1) как несколько пользовательских запросов одновременно разделяют методы и поля этого бина? 
2) корректно ли в полях синглтон бина хранить какие-либо пользовательские настройки?

Comment: > как несколько пользовательских запросов одновременно разделяют методы и поля этого бина? 

Как с любым синглтоном. Синхронизация и потокобезопасность остается на вашей совести.

> корректно ли в полях синглтон бина хранить какие-либо пользовательские настройки

Нет, как раз для этого есть session-бины.

Answer (score 1):

Не все бины имеют scope singleton по умолчанию. Например вложенные бины имеют scope prototype.

По вопросу:

1. Потоки не разделяют методов, а разделяют лишь состояние. Соответственно подхода два: либо использовать синхронизацию доступа к разделяемому состоянию, либо не иметь разделяемого состояния (еще лучше не иметь измениямого состояния, или не иметь состояния вообще).
2. Если эти пользовательские настройки нужны вам в рамках выполнения некоторой транзакции (в цепочке вызываемых методов), то рассмотрите один из двух вариантов: не хранить данные настройки в полях класса, а передавать их в качестве параметра методов, либо используйте ThreadLocal.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую перефразировать:

1) как разделяют: бин - это просто экземпляр класса, пользователи могут приходить к бину по разному, но часто это воркеты какого-нибудь API (jetty workers,...), соответственно к бину они обращаются просто как несколько конкурентных потоков, никакой синхронизации сам Spring не предлагает (но легко можно обозначить методы через synchronized, что вполне вариант, если методы легковестные и не будут узким местом)

2) пользовательские настройки в бине хранить - плохая идея, если только не известно наверняка, что пользователей 3 калеки. Можно предложить:
а) передавать во все методы какую-нить HashMap с любыми требуемыми переменными (сложнее дебажить, просто реализовать);
б) хранить данные в выделенном классе (UserContext) с ThreadLocal переменными и ввести слой, отвечающий за очистку этих переменных (просто очень часто случается, что после любого Exception от пользователя остаётся куча артефактов, вплоть до пароля, по всему приложению в таких вот внутрибиновых ThreadLocal). << ДЛЯ НАЧАЛА РЕКОМЕНДУЮ ТАК <<<

в) использовать для хранения каждого класса специфичной пользовательской информации свои бины - сервисы: AccountService, CreditCardService, OrderService,... и при необходимости получать требуемые параметры у них.